# How fix bug in delphi 7 with scale dpi?

Tags: winforms, delphi-7, dpi

Please help fix bug in delphi 7 with scale dpi.
In this sample, I use TButton with Anchor:=[akRight] and as you can see button text overflow if window setting 125 dpi scale mode.
[image]

I prepared example for demonstration:

1) Default scale
[image: Default scale]

2) Large scale ( as you see button2 is gone )
[image: Large scale]

Source code:

Unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Unit1.dfm

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 488
  Top = 196
  Width = 720
  Height = 511
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 432
    Width = 704
    Height = 41
    Align = alBottom
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 0
    DesignSize = (
      704
      41)
    object Button1: TButton
      Left = 12
      Top = 8
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Button1'
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object Button2: TButton
      Left = 616
      Top = 8
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Anchors = [akTop, akRight] 
      Caption = 'Button2'
      TabOrder = 1
    end
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 704
    Height = 432
    Align = alClient
    Caption = 'Panel2'
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Delphi 7 is not DPI aware. 15 years later, 10.2 Tokyo still doesn't handle DPI very well. The upcoming 10.3 will have more DPI fixes.

Comment: That's not a *bug in Delphi 7*. If something didn't exist at the time Delphi 7 was released, it's not a bug that it doesn't support it. It's not a bug if you buy a 1957 Chevrolet and it doesn't have a GPS unit or support Bluetooth for your phone. You're using a 15+ year old version of Delphi. Don't be surprised it doesn't work with new OS features. If you want better support for modern OSes, upgrade to a more modern version of Delphi. If you don't want to do that, you'll need to live with the lack of support for those features.

Comment: @Ken Well, it is possible to support new Windows features on Delphi 7, you just have to do extra work. I know that I supported high DPI on delphi 6 back in the day. But it doesn't come for free.

Comment: Given all of the above, I don't think what you describe is easily reproducible. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: ok guys. It's not bug of delphi. It's bug of life when upward compatibility doesn't work. I've very havy project (stable working) which wrote fifteen years and migration to the new delphi will be too expensive. And for what? Only for showing buttons? Who will be pay for this hard work? Ha-ha

Comment: Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: just added, minimal as possible ) Key point is Anchors = [akTop, akRight] for Button2

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a solution: detect all TControl's and reposition them.

```
const
 DEFAULT_DPI = 97;

function TFMain.ScaleDPI(Value: Integer) : Integer;
begin
   Result:=Ceil(Value*Screen.PixelsPerInch/DEFAULT_DPI);
end;

var i, n       : integer;
    CompFix    : array of TAnchors;

with IsForm do begin
   SetLength(CompFix, ComponentCount);
   if ( Screen.PixelsPerInch > DEFAULT_DPI ) and Scaled then
      if ( (BorderStyle = bsSizeable) or (BorderStyle = bsSizeToolWin) ) then begin
         for i:=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
            if Components[i] is TControl then
               if ( akRight in (Components[i] as TControl).Anchors ) or
                  ( akBottom in (Components[i] as TControl).Anchors ) then begin
                     CompFix[i]:=(Components[i] as TControl).Anchors;
                     (Components[i] as TControl).Anchors:=(Components[i] as TControl).Anchors - [akRight] - [akBottom] + [akLeft] + [akTop];
                  end else CompFix[i]:=[];
         ClientWidth:=ScaleDPI(ClientWidth);
         ClientHeight:=ScaleDPI(ClientHeight);
         for i:=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
            if CompFix[i] <> [] then begin
               (Components[i] as TControl).Anchors:=CompFix[i];
               end;
         end;
   end;
```

Answer (score 0):

To work properly with scaling, you must use an environment prepared for this.
there is nothing complicated and the letters will not shrink and everything will work fine.
I have a demo application that shows how to work with scaling
if the global scale of the system differs from the scale on the development aspiration also
depending on the overall scale, it is possible to adjust the scale of only the application itself.
[EXE APP DEMO](https://github.com/dvb01/DelphiScale)
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsfq4.jpg)

```
unit AmUserScale;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

//type
  type
  AmScale = class
    private
      class procedure SetScaleAppCustom(New,Old:integer);
    public
     //хранит значение  маштаба по умолчанию
     //  AppScaleDesing рекомедую выстовить в 100 при создании формы а не здесь
     //  WinScaleDPIDesing рекомедую выстовить в 96 при создании формы что равно WinApi.Windows.USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI  а не здесь
     //если вы разрабатываете прогу и у вас на компе глобальный маштаб 120 то его и установите по умолчанию в WinScaleDPIDesing
     // если у вас всегда глобальный маштаб 96 то ничего устанавливать не нужно см initialization

      class var AppScaleDesing:Integer; //  какой маштаб был на этапе разработки
      class var AppScaleNow:Integer;    //какой маштаб сейчас в приложении
      class var WinScaleDPIDesing:Integer; //какой глобальный маштаб системы был  на этапе разработки
      class var WinScaleDPINow:Integer; //какой глобальный маштаб системы сейчас в приложении
      class var IsShow:boolean;
      // при создании главной формы запустить Init
      // можно передать параметр сохраненного маштаба приложения например с какой то базы данных
      // это процент от 30 до 200 обычно это 100 процентов от размера приложения на этапе разработки
      class procedure Init(ASavedProcent:Integer=100);

      // в собыитии FormShow запустить Show
      class procedure Show;
      //  запустить в событии главной формы FormAfterMonitorDpiChanged
      // проиходит когда в системе глобально меняется маштаб
      class procedure ChangeDPI(NewDPI,OldDPI:integer);

      // получить новое значение размера для числа val смотрите ниже описание
      // если кратко то  P:=Tpanel.create(self); P.height:=  AmScale.Value(88);
      class function Value(val:integer):integer; static;

      // если хотим поменять мастаб всего приложения  SetScaleApp(120,100) увеличится на 20%
      class procedure SetScaleApp(New,Old:integer);

      // получить список для юзера возможных маштабов приложения
      class procedure GetAppToList(L:TStrings);

      // у вас есть значение но не знаете индек его в списке  = найдите
      class function GetIndexFromList(L:TStrings;value:integer=0):integer;

      // получить значение с строки которая была  получена в GetAppToList
      class function GetValueFromStr(S:String):integer;
      // изменить маштаб когда юзер выбрал новое значение из списка
      class procedure SetAppFromListInt(New:Integer);
      //передать одну линию со списка полученного в GetAppToList
      class procedure SetAppFromList(S:String);
  end;

  function UserMainScale(val:integer):integer;

{
  ЭТО СТАРОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ СМЫСЛ ТОТ ЖЕ просто имена процедур изменены

  получает маштаб экрана у пользователя на форм create занести значение в UserMainScaleGetConst

 где
 Width_now это ширина формы когда програ запускается
 Width_debag это ширина формы на этапе разработки
 в ответ приходит процент изменения , т.е маштаб
USER_MAIN_SCALE_CREATE:= UserMainScaleGetConst(MyForm.Width,500);
USER_MAIN_SCALE_CREATE хранит текуший маштаб наример 125.67 но обычно 100

далее если создаем компоненты диначимичеки то указываем ширину и высоту и отступы как
P:=Tpanel.create(self);
P.parent:=self;
P.height:=  UserMainScale(88);  //хотя раньше бы писали как  P.height:=  88;
P.font.size:=  UserMainScale(10);


  небольшое замечание по динамическому созданию котролов
  после TWinControl.Create
  и до уставновки Parent
  нужно ставить значения высот обычно т.е
  P.height:=  88;
  P.parent:=self;
  после установки  Parent
  P.height:=  UserMainScale(88);
}

implementation



{ AmScale }
function UserMainScale(val:integer):integer;
begin
   Result:=AmScale.Value(val);
end;
class procedure AmScale.GetAppToList(L: TStrings);
begin
    L.Clear;
    L.Add('70 %');
    L.Add('80 %');
    L.Add('90 %');
    L.Add('95 %');
    L.Add('100 % (рекомедуется)');
    L.Add('110 %');
    L.Add('120 %');
    L.Add('130 %');
    L.Add('140 %');
    L.Add('150 %');
    L.Add('175 %');
    L.Add('200 %');
end;
class function AmScale.GetIndexFromList(L: TStrings; value: integer=0): integer;
begin
    if value<30 then
    value:= AppScaleNow;
    for Result := 0 to L.Count-1 do
    if GetValueFromStr(L[Result]) = value then exit;
    Result:=-1;
end;

class function AmScale.GetValueFromStr(S: String): integer;
var tok:integer;
begin
    Result:=0;
    tok:=  pos(' ',S);
    if (tok<>1) and (tok<>0) then
    begin
       S:=s.Split([' '])[0];
       TryStrToInt(S,Result);
    end;
end;

class procedure AmScale.SetAppFromList(S: String);
begin
    SetAppFromListInt(GetValueFromStr(S));
end;
class procedure AmScale.SetAppFromListInt(New: Integer);
begin
   SetScaleApp(New,AppScaleNow);
end;

class procedure AmScale.SetScaleApp(New,Old:integer);
begin
   if New<30 then exit;
   if Old<30 then
   Old:= AppScaleNow;
   if Old<30 then exit;

   if New<>AppScaleNow then
   begin
       SetScaleAppCustom(New,AppScaleNow);
       AppScaleNow:= New;
   end;
end;
class procedure AmScale.SetScaleAppCustom(New, Old: integer);
var i:integer;
begin
     for  I := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do
     Screen.Forms[i].ScaleBy(New,Old);
end;

class procedure AmScale.Show;
begin
    SetScaleAppCustom(AppScaleNow,AppScaleDesing);
    IsShow:=true;
end;

class procedure AmScale.ChangeDPI(NewDPI,OldDPI:integer);
begin
  WinScaleDPINow:= NewDPI;
end;
class procedure AmScale.Init(ASavedProcent:Integer=100);
var LMonitor:TMonitor;
    LForm: TForm;
    LPlacement: TWindowPlacement;
begin
      if ASavedProcent<=0 then
      ASavedProcent:=100;
      if ASavedProcent<30 then  ASavedProcent:=30;
      if ASavedProcent>300 then  ASavedProcent:=300;

      AppScaleDesing:=100;
      AppScaleNow:=ASavedProcent;



      WinScaleDPINow:=USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;
      WinScaleDPIDesing:=USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;

      if (Application<>nil) and (Screen<>nil) then
      begin
        LMonitor := Screen.MonitorFromWindow(Application.Handle);
        if LMonitor <> nil then
          WinScaleDPINow := LMonitor.PixelsPerInch
        else
         WinScaleDPINow := Screen.PixelsPerInch;

        LForm := Application.MainForm;
        if (LForm <> nil)  then
        WinScaleDPIDesing := LForm.PixelsPerInch;


      end
      else if (Screen<>nil) and (Mouse<>nil) then
      begin
        LMonitor := Screen.MonitorFromPoint(Mouse.CursorPos);
        if LMonitor <> nil then
          WinScaleDPINow := LMonitor.PixelsPerInch
        else
         WinScaleDPINow := Screen.PixelsPerInch;

        LForm := Application.MainForm;
        if (LForm <> nil)  then
        WinScaleDPIDesing := LForm.PixelsPerInch;
      end;
           



      //ScaleForPPI(GetParentCurrentDpi);

end;

class function AmScale.Value(val: integer): integer;
begin
  // result:=Round( Value(Real(val)) );
    // сначало маштаб системы потом маштаб приложения
    result:=MulDiv(val, WinScaleDPINow, WinScaleDPIDesing);
   if IsShow then 
    result:=MulDiv(result, AppScaleNow, AppScaleDesing);
end;

 {
class procedure AmScale.Start(Width_now, Width_debag: real);
begin

     USER_SCALE:=100;
   if Width_debag=0 then exit;
   USER_SCALE:=(Width_now/Width_debag)*100;

 c:=TMonitor.Create;
 c.PixelsPerInch

end;}
initialization
begin
   AmScale.IsShow:=false;
   AmScale.AppScaleDesing:=100;
   AmScale.AppScaleNow:=100;
   AmScale.WinScaleDPIDesing:= WinApi.Windows.USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;
   AmScale.WinScaleDPINow:=    WinApi.Windows.USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

To scale your application you can set in design-time (Object Inspector) Form1.Scaled to False and then in run-time scale the form by custom factor using manual setted contant:

```
const DefaultDesignTimePPI = 96; // virtual PPI in Windows for standard font scale (100%)

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AutoScroll := false; // to resize the form window when scaling
  ChangeScale(Screen.PixelsPerInch, DefaultDesignTimePPI);
  Scaled := true;
```